# async/await seems to be blocking requests in FastAPI

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, fastapi, motorengine

I haave a challenge with `async`/`await` blocking other requests in FastAPI. My code used to work well calling requests in `def` functions. For instance:

```py
someRequestsApis = APIRouter()

someRequestsApis.get("/something/")
def getThings():
   return list(things.find())
```

Things would work well in this format. Now, I find myself for some reason having to switch from `pymongo` to `AsyncIOMotorClient`. The thing is I cannot run the motor database apis in my requests without using `async`/`await`. What used to be:

```py
def getThings():
   return list(things.find())
```

is now supposed to be:

```py
async def getThings():
   return await things.find().to_list()
```

Even the background tasks that are supposed to handle some of this logic have to be asynchronous, yet requests get blocked. I have searched for answers on this issue, yet the answer seems to suggest that the solution has to be to remove `async`/`await` in my requests and since I seem not to have such a luxury what is my work around strategy for such?

Comment: async doesn't parallize requests, so if any of these endpoints have some code that isn't async compatible could be the issue. How large is the result set returned by `getThings()`?

Comment: @MatsLindh well I am processing quite large datasets and we are talking from 100 000 to upwards. So would you suggest. Should I rather return to pymongo????

Comment: for this is an issue I cannot afford to have

Comment: Well, that depends on why you switched away from pymongo in the first place. It's hard for anyone else to make that analysis - just remember that if you're going to use async, you'll have to implement it all through the stack. If `to_list()` with 150k rows and then working with those takes a lot of time, you'll still be spending a lot of time processing those rows. In production you'll usually run multiple workers, but a CPU intensive task will block other coroutines from doing anything.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you so much. I think for now will have to revert back to my old code till I familirize myself well enough with async for me to use it

Comment: @Chris thanks a lot your answer has served me from weeks of headaches. May you help me on how do I exactly make this a duplicate question

Comment: have duplicated thanks